# How do I change time format in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to change the format of a column (serie) in pandas.

The column is datetime object in the following format: `2017-06-14 08:00:00`

I would like to format the column as: `2017-06-14T08:00Z`. Including `T` as separator and `Z` as UTC time

```
df["time(UTC)"].dt.strftime("%Y:%m%:%dT%H:%MZ")`
```

But is doesn't work.

How can I do that?

Comment: "I'm" is a proper contraction of "I am". "I´would" is not a proper contraction. It's either "I would" or "I'd".

Comment: #1. Show some code. #2 show a minimal example so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why do you have a `%` before the colon?

Comment: you have typo in `df["time(UTC)"].dt.strftime("%Y:%m%:%dT%H:%MZ")`  **Edit** before 2nd semicolon

Comment: @ksai colon* :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need change `format` only:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'time(UTC)':pd.to_datetime(['2017-06-14 08:00:00','2017-06-14 08:00:00'])})

df['new'] = df["time(UTC)"].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ")
print (df)
            time(UTC)                new
0 2017-06-14 08:00:00  2017-06-14T08:00Z
1 2017-06-14 08:00:00  2017-06-14T08:00Z
```