# changing time format in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column datetime that looks like this 2020-05-03T14:51:31.23625 (I assume  %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S)
I would like to change it to dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss format.
I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45418596/how-do-i-change-time-format-in-pandas) and I tried something similar (code below) but it works ony for the first row of the dataframe. Could someone help me to find the mistake? Thanks!

```
df['time']=pd.DataFrame({'time':pd.to_datetime(df['time'])})
df['new'] = df['time'].dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: two things: (1) I don't see why you need the first line, try `pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt...` directly. And (2), provide an example of your data (before) and the (after) result; that will help us understand exactly what you're going through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try via `split()` and `to_datetime()` method:

```
df['datetime']=pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'].str.split('.').str[0],errors='coerce')
```

Comment: I think I'm confused by the use of 'time':['2020-05-03T14:51:31.23625','2020-05-03T14:51:31.23625'] in the first line. Is python taking this as format example?

Comment: well that was a sample dataframe that I created...since you didn't provide your dataframe so I created a sample dataframe for demonstration purpose!!

Comment: @CpF Updated my answer to make you more clear...kindly have a look **:)**